# Filtering date from images of Earth Engine JRC database

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new in Google Earth Engine. I used JRC image collection which is an image of global surface water from 1984-2019.

```
var gsw = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_1/MonthlyHistory');
```

The problem is I cannot filter date from the image.
I want to filter the date from 1994 to 2003.

Is it possible to filterDate from the image or filterDaate is only applicable for images collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asset `JRC/GSW1_1/MonthlyHistory` is not an image, but an image collection, so you need to load it as one; then the filterDate operation will be available.

```
var gsw = ee.ImageCollection('JRC/GSW1_1/MonthlyHistory');
print(gsw.filterDate('1994-01-01', '2004-12-31'));
```